# Why do I get (slightly) different results everytime I run the same query on Google Bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery, floating-point, precision

I have a query on BQ that that produces slightly different results everytime I run it. Not big differences, e.g. 4421.10399999999 vs 4421.104 which looks like it is simply inconsistent rounding, but I can't understand why the same query would not be rounded the same.

I downloaded results as CSV and compared them point by point on Notebook and out of 1836 data points, 199 had these type of differences. If I rerun the query again I get a different result yet again (its also not the same data points that are different every time).

I understand that some rounding will inevitably occur to deal with the potentially infinte number of decimals, but I don't understand why the same software/data/query does this differently per execution in a seemingly random way. I tried googling it but I don't think I have a sufficiently technial vocabulary to find the reason.

I don't think it's query specific, but I included it incase.

```
SELECT 
    ms.*,
    SUM(IF(r.tou = "P", r.rate*ms.ptotal, 0)) as psavings,
    SUM(IF(r.tou = "S", r.rate*ms.stotal, 0)) as ssavings,
    SUM(IF(r.tou = "O", r.rate*ms.ototal, 0)) as osavings,
    SUM(IF(r.unit = "W" AND r.charge_calculation != "ChargeTypeCalculation", r.rate*ms.soltotal, 0)) as ls,
    SUM(IF(r.charge_calculation="MaChargeTypeCalculation", r.rate*(ms.dem), 0)) as kVA_savings,

FROM `project.table1` as ms

LEFT JOIN `project.table2` AS r
ON r.tid = ms.tid AND (ms.reporting_month BETWEEN r.start_date AND r.end_date)

GROUP BY ms.site_name, ms.reporting_month, ms.tid, ms.tg, ms.tn, ms.soltotal, ms.gtotal, ms.gmax, ms.total_kVA_max, ms.dem,     
    ms.ptotal, ms.stotal, ms.ototal

ORDER BY site_name, reporting_month
```

Comment: Is BigQuery parallelizing the work? Do you know in what ways? Even if you dispatch identical jobs each time a query is made, if you add up the results in the order the jobs complete, and the jobs complete in different orders from query to query, you can get different results, since floating-point arithmetic is not associative.

Comment: Thanks for the responses but these comments are a bit above my level of understanding (pretty new to BQ and databases in general). To the first comment, what is a worker in this sense? To the second comment, I have no idea how to find out if BQ is parallelizing the work. Also, can you elaborate on what "floating-point arithmetic is not associative" means?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property#Nonassociativity_of_floating_point_calculation

Comment: Even with multithreading it should be possible to get deterministic results (e.g., by making sure the final reduction always happens in the same order). If you verified that this is not documented behavior of BQ, I would suggest to file a bug report for that.

Comment: How would I check/make sure the final reduction always happens in the same order?